# AS3 -- Copied object properties: reference or value?

Tags: actionscript-3

(In AS3) I know when i copy a dictionary, it creates a shallow copy that i can modify without affecting the original.
If I create a copy of an object, can I modify the copy's properties without affecting the properties of the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the property type if it's an immutable value such as a string it's okay but if it is an object then you must use deep copy.

If you want a deep copy of your object that you can modify without altering the original make a util class and declare this method

```
private function clone(obj:Object):Object {
    var temp:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
     temp.writeObject(obj);
     temp.position = 0;
     return temp.readObject();
}
```

Please note that you can use `ObjectUtil.copy()` if you are using Flex.

---

**Update**: Also note that `DisplayObject` instances (or inherited classes instances) are nearly impossible to copy deeply.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. However you can use:

```
ObjectUtil.clone(object);
```

The drawback is that you can't clone UIComponents

The documentation says:

Clones the specified Object and returns a reference to the clone. The clone is made using a native serialization technique. This means that custom serialization will be respected during the cloning. clone() differs from copy() in that the uid property of each object instance is retained. 
This method is designed for cloning data objects, such as elements of a collection. It is not intended for cloning a UIComponent object, such as a TextInput control. If you want to clone specific UIComponent objects, you can create a subclass of the component and implement a clone() method.